# Model.find() returns an array instead of a query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have written this code while building an API with node js

```
const Exercise = require('../models/exerciseModel');

const { getUserById } = require('./users');

const logUser = async (req, res) => {
  const { _id } = req.params
  let { from, to, limit } = req.query

  const user = await getUserById(_id)

  if(!user)
    return res.send("not found");

  let exercises = await Exercise.find({ username : user.username})

if(limit){
    try{
      limit = parseInt(limit)
      exercises = exercises.limit(limit)
    }
    catch(error){
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

}
```

getUserById is another function that have to retrieve a user id an another collection

I expected that exercises was a query so i could chain the limit method. But, i get an error saying that exercises.limit was not a function. This is because exercises is an array of object.

Now, my question. The doc says that Model.find returns a query, why do i get an array. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`limit` should not separated with `find`

```
if (limit) {
  limit = parseInt(limit)
} else {
  limit = 9999999;
}

try {
  let exercises = await Exercise.find({ username : user.username}).limit(limit)
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```